# C++ template class with dynamic callback function type

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, callback, pure-virtual

In the code below, I want a user to be able to create a consumer class with a specific type, eg `Consumer<StateA>` so their callback function can correctly handle the type they give it. However in the code below, the compiler complains because at compile time, the call to the function in the `StateB` consume method is not generated. The consume methods come from a base class and they have to be overriden.

```
template <class T>
class Consumer : ConsumerBase
{
    public:
        Consumer(std::function<void(T&)> _callback){
            callback = _callback;
        }
        virtual void consume(StateA& state) { 
            callback(state);
        }
        virtual void consume(StateB& state) { 
            callback(state);
        }
    private:
        std::function<void(T&)> callback; 
};
```

Base Class:

```
class ConsumerBase
{
   public:
      virtual void consume(StateA& state) = 0;
      virtual void consume(StateB& state) = 0;
};
```

How can I make this work?

Comment: As best as I can decipher this question, the subclass only needs to declare one `consume()` method, with a `T &` parameter, so that it overrides the equivalent method in the superclass (and the declaration should use the `override` keyword instead of `virtual`, in order to help your compiler catch bugs in your code). If the superclass defines only abstract methods, a different approach will be needed, however since your question lacks a [mcve], as explained in stackoverflow.com's [help], no further suggestions are possible.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik thanks, I have added the base class, which has pure virtual functions that have to have overrides.

Comment: I suspect it's not that `consume(StateB&)` isn't generated, it's that it can't be compiled.  In `Consumer<StateA>` there is no `callback(StateB&)`, the only visible `callback` takes a `StateA&` so you can't compile the definition.

Comment: @jthill yes, you are correct. I meant to say the call to the (callback) function cannot be found (by the compiler) because there is no callback function generated with StateB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The consume methods come from a base class and they have to be overriden. [...] How can I make this work?

I suppose that a possible solution is develop a couple of `consume_h()` ("consume helper") methods.

The first one is an exact match for `T` (the template type of the class) that call the callback function

```
    void consume_h (T & state)
     { callback(state); }
```

The second one is a template version that do nothing

```
    template <typename U>
    void consume_h (U &)
     { }
```

Now you can override both virtual method calling `consume_h()`

```
    virtual void consume (StateA & state)
     { consume_h(state); }

    virtual void consume (StateB & state)
     { consume_h(state); }
```

This way the virtual method corresponding to `T`, call the `consume_h()` that call the callback; the other call the template `consume_h()` that do nothing.

The following is a full compiling example

```
#include <functional>

struct StateA { };
struct StateB { };

struct ConsumerBase
 {
   virtual void consume (StateA &) = 0;
   virtual void consume (StateB &) = 0;
 };

template <typename T>
class Consumer : ConsumerBase
{
    public:
        Consumer (std::function<void(T&)> cb0) : callback{cb0}
         { }

        void consume_h (T & state)
         { callback(state); }

        template <typename U>
        void consume_h (U &)
         { }

        virtual void consume (StateA & state)
         { consume_h(state); }

        virtual void consume (StateB & state)
         { consume_h(state); }

    private:
        std::function<void(T&)> callback; 
};

int main()
{
   Consumer<StateA>  csa{[](StateA &){ std::cout << "A" << std::endl; }};
   Consumer<StateB>  csb{[](StateB &){ std::cout << "B" << std::endl; }};

   StateA  sa;
   StateB  sb;

   csa.consume(sa);  // print A
   csb.consume(sb);  // print B
}
```